# Why do I get "unexpected keyword_end"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code in my rails app:

```html
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @debate.title %>
</p>

<p>
  Supporting Points:
</p>
<% @debate.supports.each.do |support| %>
<p>
  <%= support.body %>
</p>
<% end %>

<p>
  Contesting Points:
</p>
<% @debate.contests.each.do |contest| %>
<p>
  <%= contest.body %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

And I get an error "syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end" on the last line.

Whats going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be related to your broken `each` loops, this:

```
<% @debate.supports.each.do |support| %>
```

should be this:

```
<% @debate.supports.each do |support| %>
```

Note that I removed the "`.`" between "`each`" and "`do`". Your `@debate.contests` loop suffers from the same problem. That would explain the parser complaining about a stray `end` keyword (i.e. "unexpected keyword_end").